# Getting all audit where original estimate changed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a requirement to query all audit where original estimate has been changed. Is that possible with the DevOps REST api?

Comment: audit = work items?

Comment: Yes. All tasks and bugs where original has been changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this moment, I am afraid that we could not get all work items where original estimate changed through rest api.

As a workaround , we could add a custom field in our custom process that gets set the value to `true` when the original estimate field has changed  :

Note the type of the custom field is Boolean

[image]

Then add a Rules to set the value of the custom field to **true** if the original estimate field has changed (The default value of the custom Test01 field is false):

[image]

When original estimate field changed , the value of Test01 field will change from fasle to true.

Finally, we could query the **Bug** work items where original estimate changed with following conditions (the same settings to Task):

[image]

Hope this helps.